# Creating OHLC charts from ticks. Is there a library that would assist

Tags: c++, charts, finance, stock

I currently have a subscription to a service that provides historical feeds and also live Quotes.I wanted to know if there was any library out there that I could just give the ticks to and it would construct OHLC bars for different time intervals for me. So whenever i need it , i could just make a request and receive them.Any library/framework opensource or commercial preferably in C++ that might assist in this or any suggestions ?

Comment: [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml)?